# CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsed by default

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am developing an Android app and following the material design.

I am using the Toolbar throughout the whole app and it is working fine. I have one Activity where I want to use CollapsingToolbarLayout.

Problem:

When I use CollapsingToolbarLayout I cant make it collapse in all activities except the activity I want. I worked this around by having a separate layout for this activity which uses CollapsingToolbarLayout and another layout for other activities in the app which uses the normal Toolbar.

Question:

Is there a way that I can use CollapsingToolbarLayout in the whole app and only make it visible in a single activity where its needed and just the Toolbar in the rest of activities?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's what you want, but the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams.html) say, that you could use LayoutParams.setCollapseMode to COLLAPSE_MODE_OFF and so you can use the CallapsingToolbarLayout in dependency of your single activity.